React: Cannot enter a value while testing NumericFormat embedded in Controller
I have a NumericFormat as part of a react-hook-form Controller which vitest renders with jest-dom. When trying to enter some test data into it, its value does not change.
The Component:
// MoneyValueInputForm.tsx

import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { NumericFormat } from "react-number-format";
import FormInputPropsT from "@/components/form/FormInputPropsT";

const MoneyValueFormInput = ({
  fieldName,
  label,
}: FormInputPropsT): ReactElement => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      name={fieldName}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        const muiProps = {
          error: !!error,
          helperText: error ? "Must enter a value, even if 0" : null,
          label: label,
          fullWidth: true,
        };
        return (
          <NumericFormat
            thousandSeparator
            decimalScale={2}
            fixedDecimalScale
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            customInput={TextField}
            inputProps={{ "data-testid": "money-value-input" }}
            {...muiProps}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

The test code:
// my.test.tsx

import { beforeEach, describe, expect, it } from "vitest";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("Given parent form", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    // properly render parent form with initialization data 
  });
  describe("When entering amount 1234", async () => {

    let amount: HtmlElement;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      
       // this operation is actually successful
       // invoking getter method in debugger shows correct initialized value
       amount = await screen.findByTestId("money-value-input"),

       // this one isn't
       // invoking getter method in debugger still shows initialized value
       await user.type(amount, "1234");
      
    });

    it("Then should display 1,234.00", () => {
       // consequently, this fails
       expect(amount).toHaveValue("1,234.00);
    });

  });
}):


The component of course works when rendering the app in the browser; the element in question looks like this, clearly showing an <input ..> with my data-testid and a value of 0.00, which is the initialization:
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth MuiTextField-root mui-wb57ya-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root" inputmode="numeric">
  <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-sizeMedium MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-sizeMedium MuiInputLabel-outlined mui-zv3br2-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root" data-shrink="true" for=":r4:" id=":r4:-label">
    Amount
  </label>
  <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl mui-1rbu2s8-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root">
    <input aria-invalid="false" id=":r4:" data-testid="money-value-input" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input mui-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input" type="text" value="0.00">
    <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline mui-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
      <legend class="mui-14lo706">
          <span>Amount</span>
      </legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>

I have even tried something hopeless like this:
async function enterAmount(input: HTMLElement, amount: string) {
  await user.click(input);
  for (let i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
    await user.keyboard(amount[i]);
  }
}

I must be missing something obvious ...
